# Should the RTP feed from a surveillance camera be protected?

Tags: encryption, video

I see a lot of camera system and they're either using RSTP over RTP or just RTP.  Most of the times they are on straight HTTP for the login, some will be on HTTPS, but unless forced (which I have seen), the video feeds do not tunnel through the HTTPS.  Should they be forced through HTTPS or implement SRTP or RSTPS?

Comment: Should it be protected? Yes. Are you really asking about https vs srtp/rstps?

Comment: @Schroeder well, that's the thing, I am not as familiar with the RTP and RTSP. Any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated. / I do know that RTP does a better job for latency, but I don't know if routing it through https would be that bad. One way or the other it would make it more secure

Comment: Be careful with network cameras as their firmware is often crap and contains vulnerabilities and/or backdoors. I recommend putting them behind a secure VPN gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication/Login should always be done over HTTPS if its an viable option, consider just the amount of admins that uses the same passwords for different systems. There are so many reasons.

RTP is from 1989 originally, and to run anything over it today should almost be criminal. If it have any form of security perspective, a bad guy could DOS the camera feed or send a faked time-loop (like they do in the movies, yes we actually did that in our office for a demonstration).

I'd use one of those two, and make sure to enable both authentication and encryption (both optional).